# Finding all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $ \mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(A)$ for fixed $A$ algebraic

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, ring-isomorphism

As an example, if we put $F =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, ... , \sqrt{n})$, $F$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$ so that we can write

$$
p(x) = (x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)\cdots (x^2 - n).
$$

Question: if it is always true the isomorphism above (I'm not sure there is a counter-example for a general case), how can I find all polynomials $p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(A)$ for a fixed algebraic $A$ (or a series of extensions for that matter)?

Are they the [irreducible] polynomials which are multiples of $p(x)$, when $p(x)$ is such that $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ is its splitting field?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing on first reading. I think you mean "How to find all polynomials ... where $A$ is a set of algebraic numbers". Is that right, if so please fix.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ is a field, you need $(p(x))$ to be maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, which holds if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$; in which case, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ (in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$). So for a fixed algebraic number $A$, this holds if and only if $p(x)$ is the a nonzero scalar multiple of the irreducible polynomial of $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: “Wouldn’t the polynomial be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$”? Techincally, it would be irreducible **in** $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but for fields, we typically speak about a polynomial being irreducible **over** a field $k$ if its coefficients lie in $k$, and the polynomial is irreducible in $k[x]$. This is common nomenclature.

Comment: What do you mean, “it happens that other irreducible polynomials can work”? No, for a particular algebraic number $\alpha$, no other polynomials will work except for the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ and its associates.

Comment: You seem to be confusing $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ with the splitting field of $p(x)$. Note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to the field obtained by adjoining to $\mathbb{Q}$ a **single** root of $p(x)$. This may, or may not, be the same as the splitting field of $p(x)$. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$ is **not** isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2-5))$, as the latter is actually isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\times\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. However, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$ **is** isomorphic to the splitting field of $(x^2-2)(x^2-5)$ (cont)$

Comment: (cont) It is also **equal** to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for infinitely many $\alpha$ (all $\alpha$ of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that lie in that splitting field). Are you asking how to find all $\alpha$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(A)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: “An example” of **what**? I don’t understand what you are trying to say. And what does failing Eisenstein’s criterion have to do with the price of tea in China?

Comment: The question in your title is ambiguous and you do nothing to clarify in the body of your question.  Do you mean "Find all $p$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[z]/(p(z)) \cong \mathbb{Q}(A)$ for some $A$ in the algebraics." or do you mean "For a given, fixed $A$ in the algebraics, find all $p$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[z]/((p(z)) \cong \mathbb{Q}(A)$."  The latter is a vastly smaller set than the former (for certain definitions of smaller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Primitive Element Theorem, an algebraic extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite. Not all such extensions are given by splitting fields, however.

For $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, let $n=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\colon\mathbb{Q}]$. Then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\deg(p)=n$, and there is a root $\beta$ of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. There are going to be infinitely many such polynomials (for example, all $\beta=q_1\alpha+q_2$ with $q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{Q}$, $q_1\neq 0$ will do), and I suspect you’ll find it rather difficult to find all such polynomials. Even with something like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, you have infinitely many elements of degree $4$ in that field, generally written as $q$-linear combinations of $1+\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{6}$.

Of course, they can all be written as $q$-linear combinations of $1$, $\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ (since these elements form a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ as a vector space), but not all such combinations work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I get it from reading: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161233/657449.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some facts:

- Not every finite algebraic extension is a splitting field. For instance $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not a splitting field.
- Every finite algebraic extension is of the form $\mathbb Q(\theta)$, for some algebraic number $\theta$, and so is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x)$ for some irreducible polynomial $p$. This is the contents of the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

For simplicity, I'm talking here about finite algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @RickAlmeida: In general you do **not** have that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))\cong \mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$. That will only hold if the extension is a normal extension. Generally, you only get **one** root of $p(x)$ in the extension. If you started with a polynomial $p(x)$, the splitting field will be $\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_n)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))$ for some $\beta$ and $q(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ (by the Primitive Element Theorem). But $q(x)$ is **not necessarily**  the $p$ you started with.

Comment: And, no, you don’t get a unique $p(x)$, because in general there are **infinitely many** $\beta$ that work, and they can’t all come from the same poluynomial.

Comment: @RickAlmeida: If you start with $p(x)$, then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is not, in general, a normal extension; and the splitting field of $p(x)$ is not, in general, equal to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$. For example, take $p(x) = x^3-2$. Then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x)) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$,which is *not* a normal extension; and the splitting field of $p(x)$ is **not** $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$. However, if $F$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$, there does exist a $\beta$ in $F$ (in fact, infinitely many such $\beta$s) such that $F=\mathbb{Q}(\beta) \cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))$, (cont)

Comment: @RickAlmeida (cont) where $q(x)$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\beta$. There are infinitely many such $q(x)$ that will “work”, because there are infinitely many $\beta$s that work. But $q(x)$ is **not** $x^3-2$, the polynomial we started with.